# CAST STRING as INT64

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column that has a number saved as string.

How can I convert this into int64 or any other number format? I have tried CAST but it gives me an error "Bad int64 value: 1.99" Its because of decimal point I am getting an error. How can I get around this.

[image]

Comment: SELECT PARSE_NUMERIC("123.45")

Comment: also CAST AS NUMERIC

Comment: In your own words, when you try to use the `int64` type, what do you think that name means? In particular, what do you think the `int` part means?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do these steps to convert your decimal string to an integer:

1. Parse the String into a decimal number using [PARSE_NUMERIC()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#parse_numeric)
2. Round your number to get it to an integer using [CEIL()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#ceil) or [FLOOR()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#floor)
3. [CAST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_as_integer) the result to `INT64`

   SELECT CAST( FLOOR( PARSE_NUMERIC( '99.99' ) )  AS INT64 ) AS output

   Output: 99